# How to NOT use ksshaskpass with ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

When using [`ssh-agent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent)  I want to always enter my passphrase into a terminal, but [`ksshaskpass`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksshaskpass) keeps popping up because the environmental variable `SSH_ASKPASS` is set, even though I'm not setting it myself.  What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

There's two ways to deal with the problem:

1. Remove the package (usually `ksshaskpass`) associated with `/etc/xdg/plasma-workspace/env/ksshaskpass.sh`, as this is where `SSH_ASKPASS` is being set.
2. Add the line `unset SSH_ASKPASS` to your `.bashrc` file.